# How to pass data to a component not via HTML

Tags: angular

I have a component where I have reference to another component.

```
readonly componentA: typeof ComponentA = ComponentA;
```

I want to pass a value from the component where I have this reference in the `ngOnInit` method. What's the best way to achieve this? Now I do use

```
this.componentA.prototype.myVariable = value;
```

Can it stay like this, or it's better to use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ViewChild()` decorator and set the value in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild(ComponentA) component;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.component.inputName = 'my value';
 }
}
```

here is a link to stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ovfzqg?file=app/app.component.ts